# How to read ultrasonic sensor data from the guidance system through mobile api?

Tags: dji-sdk

I have a N3 product and I want to read the ultrasonic data of the guidance system from the mobile SDK. I'm not very experienced with the DJI product so I would like some information to make the two system communicate.

Thanks for your help,

Gino.

Comment: Are you talking about using Guidance SDK and Mobile SDK?

Comment: Yes, the only API I found is https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/android-api/Components/FlightController/DJIFlightController_DJIFlightControllerCurrectState.html#djiflightcontroller_djiflightcontrollercurrectstate_ultrasonicheight_inline. I I would like to get data from all the sensors.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only to use the N3 with guidance you can connect the guidance with your N3 with modified cable. check this
https://rm-static.djicdn.com/documents/19806/6e3c55a1cbb391557376462460973698.pdf

Comment: This answer could be better if you explain the steps or summarize key portions of the link's contents directly in the post.